# PHP array_unique is not returning unique values

Tags: php, arrays, array-unique

I have an array below in which I want to get or remove duplicate values:

```
$data = $responses;
var_dump($data);
```

result is:

```
array(11) {
  [0]=>
    string(4) "date"
  [1]=>
     string(4) "name"
  [2]=>
     string(10) "start_time"
  [3]=>
     string(8) "end_time"
  [4]=>
     string(4) "date"
  [5]=>
     string(4) "name"
  [6]=>
     string(10) "start_time"
  [7]=>
     string(8) "end_time"
  [8]=>
     string(7) "other_1"
  [9]=>
     string(7) "other_2"
  [10]=>
     string(7) "other_3"
}
```

So I do :

```
var_dump(array_unique($data));
//also tried:
var_dump(array_intersect_key($data, array_unique(array_map('serialize', $data))));
```

but the output is:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
    string(4) "date"
  [1]=>
     string(4) "name"
  [2]=>
     string(10) "start_time"
  [3]=>
     string(8) "end_time"
  [4]=>
     string(7) "other_1"
  [5]=>
     string(7) "other_2"
  [6]=>
     string(7) "other_3"
}
```

The output I am expecting is:

```
array(3){
  [1]=>
     string(7) "other_1"
  [2]=>
     string(7) "other_2"
  [3]=>
     string(7) "other_3"
}
```

I am expecting to have the last 3 items to be returned only for they are the only values that are not duplicate, but I think `array_unique` is just retaining one single value of the duplicate items.
Am I doing `array_unique` the right way?

Comment: @mickmackusa thanks for the redirection, but the output is like this : `array (
  0 => 'other_1',
  1 => 'other_2',
  2 => 'other_3',
)NULL` . can we remove NULL?

Comment: If you need the keys to start from `1`, then use `array_unshift()` a dummy value to the array, then `unset()` it.  If my other answer helped you, you may upvote it.

Comment: @mickmackusa I mean the `NULL` after the parenthesis.

Comment: @mickmackusa I have just copied the code from your answer on that link :)

Comment: I am suggesting that it is something else in your code that is generating NULL (beyond my snippet).

Comment: https://3v4l.org/eYIia

Comment: @mickmackusa Okay. I have sorted it out. Can we store this one to an array? I have tried typecasting it, but doesn't work.

Comment: I don't understand your question extension.  You can show me in a 3v4l link and I can review your attempt if you like.  Are you asking how to push it into another array?  You may accept the duplicate that I have provided.

Comment: @mickmackusa Yes, I want them to be an array, or create the result to an array.

Comment: The result is an array (with 3 elements in it).  You'll need to better describe what you desire.

Comment: @mickmackusa just got it (phew) just removed `var_export`